# excepción al tratar de conectar base de datos con formulario

Tags: java, mysql

Buenos días, trato de conectar mi base de datos a mi proyecto en java pero me lanza la siguiente excepción

> public class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver extends com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver implements java.sql.Driver

Realmente soy muy nuevo en esto y no comprendo muy bien el error, si es por el archivo .jar, lo tengo añadido al proyecto en las librerías referenciadas. De antemano ¡muchas gracias! 
éste es el código de conexión

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConexionBD { 
private static String servidor="jdbc:mysql://localhost/prodemios"; 
private static String user="admin"; private static String pass="";  
private static String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; private static   
Connection conexion;

public ConexionBD(){

try {
Class.forName(driver);
conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(servidor,user,pass);
System.out.print("Conexión realizada con exito");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
System.out.print("Conexión fallida");
 }
} 

public Connection getConnection(){ 
return conexion;
}
```

Y este es el que lo llama

```
public void insertar() { 
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("ingresa cantidad de usuarios");
cantidad=leer.nextInt();
for(i=0;i<=cantidad-1;i++){

cont=cont+1;
System.out.println("ingresa el nombre del usuario numero "+cont);
usuariosNombre=leer.next();
System.out.println("ingresa los puntos del usuario numero "+cont);
usuariosPuntos=leer.nextInt();
} 

conexion=new ConexionBD();
Connection con=conexion.getConnection();
Statement st=null;
String Sql="insert into prodemios (nombre,puntos) values ('"+usuariosNombre+"','"+usuariosPuntos+"')";

try {
st=con.createStatement();

st.executeUpdate(Sql);
con.close();
st.close();
System.out.println("insertado con exito");
} catch ( SQLException e) {
    System.out.print("Conexión fallida");
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Claro que sí, tuve que responder a mi pregunta, por que no me cabía el código en el comentario para responderte directamente, muchas gracias por tu interés, el código está mas abajo

Comment: Cuando el error se muestra te indica qué linea es la que está involucrada. Verifica que tengas el Driver agregado tal como indicas en la pregunta.

Comment: es aquí donde lanza la excepción: Class.forName(driver);  ¿es a lo que te refieres?

Answer (score 1):

No has puesto el puerto en la declaración de `jdbc:mysql://localhost/prodemios`. Tienes que poner el puerto tambien. El puerto por defecto para MySQL es `3306`. Así que será `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prodemios`.

Comment: ya lo intenté tambien y nada, estoy buscando el error desde el driver, por que cuando llega al class for name (driver) me lanza la excepción de que falta el driver en el classpatch

Comment: buscando la solución*

Comment: Otra cosa que podrías hacer, y también yo lo hago es en lugar de buscar el driver desde el classpath, descarga el driver y colócalo en su bibloteca del IDE, por ejemplo (Eclipse, Intellij). Yo lo hago así y ya no me da errores ni lanza excepciónes.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu clase y la mia que te pongo que si funciona

```
 private String bd = "newmundo";
    private String login = "root";
    private String password = "";
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + bd;
    private Connection conn = null;

    public Connection Conectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.login, this.password);
            if (conn != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión a base de datos " + bd + " lista");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        conn = null;
        String mensaje = "La conexion a la  base de datos " + bd + " ha terminado";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
    }
`
```

El error debe estar en el driver lo tienes metido en las librerias?